# Spilt Name field in SQL into First Name and Last Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called name that stores the entire name. I want to split it into First Name and Last Name in a Select statement. The problem is that the name might be stored like:
Mike Joe or Mike & Sarah Smith.
If it is only two names (first and last) I can use this code:

```
, substring(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name)+1, len(name)-(CHARINDEX(' ', name)-1)) as [LastName]
, left(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name)) as [FirstName]
```

But if the name is "Mike & Sarah Smith" I want it to be like:
First Name: Mike & Sarah
Last Name:  Smith

How do I modify the code above to handle both situations?

Comment: No parsing technique is going to handle all cases. Data cleansing software is expensive for a reason - it's not just RegEx, there's some brains to it, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the last part is always the *last name* then you can use `reverse` function with `right` and `left` functions:

```
select 
left('Mike & Sarah Smith',
      len('Mike & Sarah Smith')-charindex(' ',reverse('Mike & Sarah Smith'))) FirstName,
right('Mike & Sarah Smith',charindex(' ',reverse('Mike & Sarah Smith')))  LastName
```

*Output:*

```
FirstName        LastName
Mike & Sarah     Smith
```

just put the name of your field instead of `'Mike & Sarah Smith'` in the code when using it for the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by looking for the last space in a name using `CHARINDEX()` coupled with `REVERSE()`:

```
SELECT RIGHT(name,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(name))-1) AS LastName
      ,LEFT(@name,LEN(name) - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(name))-1) AS FirstName
```

Names without spaces will present issues, so you may need to add a `CASE` expression to the above to ensure they have a space.

Comment: This will return nothing if firstname and last name are the same, or if a part of firstname be the same as lastname, correct?

Comment: What if the name is `Mike & Sarah Van der Wal`?